# Can someone code a simple JS code for me?

Tags: javascript, css

I do not understand JS at all I'm afraid. I only know HTML and CSS. Otherwise, I wouldn't be asking XD

So, what I want is something like:

```
If .remove contains "N/A", then display:none;
Else, display:block;
```

I know it's probably super super simple but I don't know JS and it scares me. If anyone can code something that does this for me I'd greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: This is for a forum.

.remove is a span class that contains a custom profile field that, when left empty, displays N/A. So, if it is left empty, I don't want it to display N/A I want it to not show up at all (Hence, display:none;). If it is filled it, I want it to be visible and show up. I've tried a few other codes that claim to work but they don't, such as

```
<script>
$('.remove:contains("N/A")').remove();
</script>
```

The original coder of this script said to include the span classed with 'remove' around the field.

EDIT2: I've used the code, and am using the code. It works kinda like it should, but when I have text in the field instead of leaving it empty it remains un-shown.

EDIT3: Section of the profile template. Field 9 and 10 are the ones I want hidden when no text. I used the codes and they still did not display when there WAS text.

```
<div style="width:200px;padding: 5px 0;background:#100E12;font-size:10px;font-family:times;font-variant:small-caps;letter-spacing:1px;"><!-- |field_8| -->
<span class="remove"><!-- |field_9 --></span>
<span class="remove"><!-- |field_10 --></span></div>
```

---

SOLUTION (Mehmet Eren Yener)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  var text = $('.remove').text()

  if(text == 'n/a','N/A')
  {
       $('.remove').css('display','none');            
  }
  else
  {
  }

});
```

Comment: Don't be scared. If you can come up with that much logic, you can probably learn to do that in javascript pretty easily.

Comment: Give more information and provide some html code....

Comment: i can help you, but be honest, give me what you want, the something what you want in above is i dont know what you means

Comment: What is `.remove` referring to? Is that a selector?

Comment: I editted. .remove refers to a css class.

Comment: @user3024230 for your example code you just added, do you also have jQuery included on the page? Because that code looks fine.

Comment: I don't know, I thought it was JS (shows how much I know) and I think it is... I don't know. The forum is http://xaiyannax.jcink.net/

I don't understand why it keeps getting downvoted.. it's a simple question that I don't know how to do/the answer to. :(

Comment: jQuery is there already, so it should work. Put the script at the very bottom of your page, or wrap the code like this: `$(function(){` original code here `});`

Comment: It does, until the field has something in it. When I added text into the field, it doesn't show like it's supposed to.

Comment: The CODE is for a forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/Sk3QY/)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  $( "#button" ).click(function() {       
      var textVal = $("#textBox").val();
          if(textVal == "") {
               $('#textBox').css('display','none');            
          }
    });
});
```

When text box is empty and submit button pressed, textbox will be disappeared.This is a simple form empty validation and if you want to use it with span class it will be same. If you dont want it to activate by button click

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {          
    var textVal = $("#textBox").val();
    if(textVal == "") {
        $('#textBox').css('display','none');            
     }
});
```

Comment: Its not a text box though... its a custom profile field that members edit.

Comment: As in it's not on the page. People edit the profile field in the control panel, hit submit.  its not on the profile, here's an example. http://xaiyannax.jcink.net/index.php?showtopic=64 Under 'Haunting" in the mini-profile it's supposed to say "dark matter"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/Sk3QY/1/ can you check here when you add somethink on div, it will appear, when the div itself is empty, it will disappear

Comment: That's a LOT closer to what I want. But, it's not going to be empty, it's going to have N/A which is default "empty" status.

Comment: only N/A or any other words

Comment: JUST N/A, because if it's empty that's what it defaults to :)

Comment: Got it! Thank you SOO much! I fiddled around with the stuff I did know within your code, and was able to get it to work! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
   if($('.remove').text() == "N/A") {
      $(this).remove();
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This does the same thing the other one did :/ Hides it (sorta) and doesn't show when there IS text.

Comment: -_- , absolutely i dont know what you want is.. Tell me on email, story tell me if you cant :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        span.remove{
            background: #fc0;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 3px;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.remove').each(function(){
            var data = $(this).text();
            if(data == 'N/A') {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="remove">N/A</span>
    <span class="remove">Data</span>
    <span class="remove">N/A</span>
    <span class="remove">Data</span>
    <span class="remove">Data</span>
    <span class="remove">N/A</span>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score -2):

```
if (.remove == "N/A") {
     //display none
} else {
     //display block
}
```

I'm assuming .remove is a defined variable and N/A is a string. Also, is the 'display ***_*_**' part of your HTML? i.e. you need to use the DOM to access the HTML object block?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's meant to be a CSS selector.

Comment: OP has to provide more information @user3024230

Comment: .remove is a css class. The original coder said to surround the field in a span that had the class 'remove'